# How to search data using searchview?

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, searchview

```
public Cursor searchByInputText(String inputText) throws SQLException {

    String query = "SELECT tag as _id," +
            TABLE_CONTACTS +  " from " + TABLE_CONTACTS +
            " where " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " MATCH '" + inputText + "';";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor Cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (Cursor != null) {
        Cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return Cursor;

}
```

I tried above code, but I am not able to search.

I am trying to get tag field data whatever stored in my database, once I search in search box it is not showing any data from my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [setOnQueryTextListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnQueryTextListener%28android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener%29) of SearchView

something like that:

```
new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener( ) {
    @Override
    public boolean   onQueryTextChange( String newText ) {
        // this is called when text changes in SearchView 
        textView.setText(newText);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean   onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // this is called when Search Button is clicked
        textView.setText(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: am not getting...if i search tag whatever tag stored in database(sq lite) should display search list...